# acceptance testing with selenium and codeception, browser shows blank page

Tags: selenium, yii2, codeception, acceptance-testing

I'm using codeception with Yii2 and my configuration is as follows:

```
class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
enabled:
    - WebDriver:
        url: 'http://ucms.ac.ir/admin/index-test.php/'
        browser: chrome
    - tests\codeception\common\_support\FixtureHelper
    - Yii2
config:
    Yii2:
        configFile: '../config/backend/acceptance.php'
```

tests run, and they finish successfully, but nothing appears on the new browser tab opened by selenium. I've seen some tutorials and in those tutorials browser actually shows process of testing. also, when an error occurs and a screenshot is taken by codeception for later reference, it's only a white empty page too. 
I'm on ubuntu 14.10, selenium 2.47.1 and chrome 45. it also happens when I use firefox instead of chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked same question in [codeception's github repo](https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/2320) and here's the answer:

> Don't use Yii2 and WebDriver in the same suite.

My fault, this is corrected configs:

```
class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - WebDriver:
            url: 'http://ucms.ac.ir/admin/index-test.php/'
            browser: chrome
        - tests\codeception\common\_support\FixtureHelper
```